# Git: can I store known repository in the repository?

Tags: remote, git, repository

I am setting up a Git repository. I know you can add repositories using `git config --global`, but is there a way that those known repositories gets cloned by users?

For example, I add git://X/mobility.git as X to the repo (somehow), a user clone it from git://Y, but then can do `git push X` without previously doing the `git config` ?

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [git submodules](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html).  Essentially, it's a way to keep the latest commit of an external repository inside a certain repository.